# Determine value of $m$

Tags: trigonometry

Consider $m = \tan x + \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x}$ . Now determine $m$ so that expression has solution .

I used Wolfram to find range of $f(x) = \tan x + \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x}$ but it was unable to find it!

Comment: what you mean about "expression has solution"

Comment: @user420255 This is the exactly same statement of the question . I think it's equal to find range of $f(x)$

Comment: It may help that $\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x - \cos x} = -\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$. Then symmetry should help find the local extrema.

Comment: @S.H.W So, the range is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes it's very nice idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$m=\tan x+\frac{\tan x+1}{\tan x-1}\implies m\tan x-m=\tan^2x-\tan x+\tan x+1\implies$$

$$\tan^2x-m\tan x+m+1=0$$

The discriminant of this quadratic in $\;\tan x\;$ must be non-negative, so it must be

$$\Delta=m^2-4m-4\ge0\iff\;\ldots$$

and we're done since $\;\tan x\;$ is onto $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: Brilliant! Can you explain why wolfram can't determine the range ?

Comment: Because in some cases, as it is been shown many times in this site, WA sucks...meaning: one must be very careful when using those online resources. They can be very helpful but a critic mind is needed.

Comment: But here we don't have $m^2-4m+4$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Good catch, thanks. Anyway, the condition for $\;m\;$ is there to be evaluated. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

$m = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x}$

$m = \frac{\sin x(\sin x - \cos x) +\cos x(\sin x + \cos z)}{\cos x(\sin x - \cos x)}$

$m = \frac{\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}x}{\sin x \cos x - \cos^{2}x}$

$(\sin x \cos x - \cos^{2}x)m - 1 = 0$

$(\tan x - 1)m - (1+\tan^{2}x) = 0$

$tan^{2}x - m\tan x +m+1 = 0$

This has real solutions when the discriminant is greater than or equal to $0$:

$m^{2} - 4(m+1) \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow (m+2)^{2} \geq 0$

So it has solutions $\forall m \in \mathbb{R}$

The range is $\tan x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: DId you notice my answer? It is exactly the same central idea with some makeup...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't, was tunnel visioned on writing my own xD

Comment: @mrnovice Fair enough. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an arbitrary x value, such as $\pi$, and see what the expression gives. For x=$\pi$, this gives -1, so we know that for an m value of -1, the expression will have a solution.

Comment: This is a rather poor approach: are you going to try **all** the real numbers that way?